# Passing functions as arguments

Tags: python, function, arguments

I know that something very basic is wrong here which I just fail to see. I'd really appreciate if somebody more experienced in Python could point out where I misunderstood things here. I post a simplified version of my code below. To trace back where the problems start, have an eye on the following:

The `MainProgram`, instanciated as `Main = MainProgram()`, has a menu (`self.menu = Startmenu()`) which is an instance of the `Menu` class. This `Menu` class has a list of buttons (`self.buttons = [...]`) - in this case only one. They are an instance of the `Button` class. I now need to pass the function to be triggered when the button is clicked to that instance of the `Button` class, so I can actually use it.

I would really be thankful to any more experienced user having a quick glance at it. I'm sure I'm failing to see something very basic. I bet I'm too tired to see it... Had only some 2 hours sleep since there's a baby in the house now :D

My code:

```
class MainProgram:
    #Much much more code
    def __init__(self):
        #And so much more code here
         self.menu = StartMenu()

class StartMenu:
    def __init__(self):
        #Much code which is not important to us here
        self.buttons = [Button("d_bt_start", (100, 60)
                                       , testfunc, "TEST-TEXT")]

class Button:
    def __init__(self, image, pos = (0, 0), path = Paths.path_img
                 , alpha = False, func = None, args = None):
        self.img_normal = helper.loadImage(path, image + "_normal.jpg", alpha)
        self.img_hover = helper.loadImage(path, image + "_hover.jpg", alpha)

        self.image = self.img_normal

        self.pos = pos

        self.x = pos[0]
        self.y = pos[1]
        self.width = self.x + self.image.get_width()
        self.height = self.y + self.image.get_height()

        self.mouseover = 0

        self.func = func
        self.args = args

    def update(self, (mx, my)):
        if (mx >= self.x and mx <= self.width and
            my >= self.y and my <= self.height):
            if self.mouseover == 0:
                self.image = self.img_hover
                self.mouseover = 1
        else:
            if self.mouseover == 1:
                self.image = self.img_normal
                self.mouseover = 0

    def clicked(self, button):
        if (mx >= self.x and mx <= self.width and
            my >= self.y and my <= self.height):
            if button == 1:
                self.func(self.args)
```

What should happen: The main file creates an instance of the `StartMenu` class. In the `StartMenu` class we define one button as an instance of the `Button` class. That button should trigger the function `testfunc(args)` upon being clicked. This testfunction is so far just a print of the "TEST-TEXT" argument.

If I pass the function as

```
testfunc
```

then I get the following error Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python27\_RPG DEMO\DEMO\main.py", line 41, in <module>
   Main = MainProgram()
  File "D:\Python27\_RPG DEMO\DEMO\main.py", line 21, in __init__
    self.menu = menus.StartMenu()
  File "D:\Python27\_RPG DEMO\DEMO\menus.py", line 11, in __init__
    , zztestfile.testfunc, "TESTEST")
  File "D:\Python27\_RPG DEMO\DEMO\buttons.py", line 7, in __init__
    self.img_normal = helper.loadImage(path, image + "_normal.jpg", alpha)
  File "D:\Python27\_RPG DEMO\DEMO\helper.py", line 13, in loadImage
    return pygame.image.load(os.path.join(folder, name)).convert_alpha()
  File "D:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 96, in join
    assert len(path) > 0
TypeError: object of type 'function' has no len()
```

If I pass it as:

```
testfunc("TEST-TEXT")
```

it triggers but then causes the following Traceback:

```
TEST-TEXT

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python27\_RPG DEMO\DEMO\main.py", line 41, in <module>
    Main = MainProgram()
  File "D:\Python27\_RPG DEMO\DEMO\main.py", line 21, in __init__
    self.menu = menus.StartMenu()
  File "D:\Python27\_RPG DEMO\DEMO\menus.py", line 11, in __init__
    , testfunc("TEST-TEXT"))
  File "D:\Python27\_RPG DEMO\DEMO\buttons.py", line 7, in __init__
    self.img_normal = helper.loadImage(path, image + "_normal.jpg", alpha)
  File "D:\Python27\_RPG DEMO\DEMO\helper.py", line 15, in loadImage
    return pygame.image.load(os.path.join(folder, name)).convert()
  File "D:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 96, in join
    assert len(path) > 0
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

I've gone through a few tutorials so far, but I really can't figure out where I'm misunderstanding them. I'd really appreciate any help in this!

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but Python 2 classes should aways inherit from `object`; using old-style classes in new code is a Bad Idea.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: It's an external function (from another module) which loads images and converts them for pygame. Since it's not relevant to the question I didn't explain anything about it here, but if you're interested we can discuss it as well.

Comment: @Wooble: Thank you for your comment. I'm really desperately searching for more in-depth information about such things as it seems that tutorials always take it for granted that people already know it :/ So I'd really appreciate any information you can provide, I'm keen to learn better :D

Comment: @PatricHartmann: No, it was a red herring; I was trying to figure out how you managed to pass a function through to the `os.path.join()` function before I realized what was going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing your test function to the *`path`* argument of your `Button` class:

```
self.buttons = [Button("d_bt_start", (100, 60)
                               , testfunc, "TEST-TEXT")]
```

That's the 3rd positional argument there:

```
def __init__(self, image, pos = (0, 0), path = Paths.path_img
             , alpha = False, func = None, args = None):
```

matching up with `path`. Use keyword arguments instead:

```
self.buttons = [Button("d_bt_start", (100, 60)
                               , func=testfunc, args="TEST-TEXT")]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! In German we have a proverb, that there are so many trees that you don't see the forest anymore... That's what happened to me and you guided me the right way.

Comment: The same proverb works in English too (though I do know it in Dutch and German as well) :-) *Not seeing the forest for the trees*.

Comment: That's interesting to know, I'm quite into linguistics :D Another hobby of mine that gets much less attention than it deserves...
By the way: it perfectly works now... It's embarassing, I have to admit, to make such a mistake and not finding it... :D